# List on button click

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm making a timetable app for the local public transport users. I'm totally new for this whole WP8 app building and xaml and so on, so -unsurprisingly- i've got a bit stucked. So i've built the main page, which contains buttons for each lines.
I want that if the user clicks the button, a list of the stops appears and he can choose one, and then the app navigates to the choosen stop's schedule. 
I've already done the stops' pages, i just have to connect the main page with the schedule- the mentioned way.

So the main question: how to open a (full screen) list by a button-click, and then navigate to another page?

[image: The plan]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you use mvvm? By that I mean to ask the following: Do you use viewmodels for your stop list as well as for your stop shedules?

Comment: Take a look at the "Windows Phone Databound App" Windows Phone project in Visual Studio. I think it will get you exactly what you need

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what is a viewmodel :) I'm really-really new, and i'm learning this autodidactitally :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create two pages, one with the List of Stops and another one with the stop's schedule.

In the XAML file of the ListOfStops Page you need to display all the records. You can use a LongListSelector to do it:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="stopsLLS" SelectionChanged="stopsLLS_SelectionChanged">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

The ItemsSource of the long list selector is a list of the stops (Use ObservableCollection if you want it to update automatically when the source changes).

```
class Stop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I put up the selection changed event to set up before navigating to the Stop's Schedule Page.

```
    private void stopsLLS_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If selected item is null (no selection) do nothing
        if (stopsLLS.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        // Save Selected Item
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["SelectedStop"] = stopsLLS.SelectedItem as Stop;

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/StopSchedulePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected item to null (no selection)
        reportsLLS.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

In the StopSchedulePage you can retrieve the Stop the following way:

```
            object o;
            if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.TryGetValue("SelectedStop", out o))
            {
                var stop = (Stop)o;
            }
```

You can display it anyway you want

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm trying to understand this, but i think this is not what i'm searching for. I've updated the question with a picture. So on the main screen there are a lot of buttons (there are 42 lines in the town). When i click on a button, a listbox appears that would be great if that would be this [full screen listbox-thing](http://www.7tutorials.com/files/img/winphone8_lock_screen/wplsc8.png). <br/> And if i choose one, it navigates its own page. But there are 40 lines, and they have different stops.

Comment: Now that I see your picture, what I explained is the Page 2 and Page 3. In the page with all the buttons you need to create a click event, save the Line, then navigate to the Page 2. Listen to @ShawnKedrot and take a look at the Windows Phone Databound App Template in Visual Studio, it will make it all clearer.